# DJCelery not storing task results in Django SQLite DB

Tags: django, sqlite, rabbitmq, celery, djcelery

`DJCelery` is not storing task results in my `Django` `SQLite` DB.

I have an existing Django project that I have started setting up Celery w/ RabbitMQ on. I started my RabbitMQ server. I can run Celery `python manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG` and Celerybeat `python manage.py celerybeat --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG`. Everything starts up w/ out error and my periodic example tasks also runs without error.

I used `pip install django-celery` to install. I have djcelery in my installed apps and ran `python manage.py migrate djcelery`. I added `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'` to the end of my settings.py file.

When I run `python manage.py celeryd --verbosity=2 --loglevel=DEBUG`, the startup text shows:

```
...
- ** ---------- .> transport: amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
...
```

The results section being blank indicates to me that the configuration isn't right somehow but I can't figure out how. I tried using app.conf.update in my celery.py file to set the CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND but got the same results. I left out CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, but that defaulted to no results. I also tried putting `'database'` instead of `'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'` but that indicated it was attempting to use `sqlalchemy` instead of `djcelery`.

When I run `python manage.py runserver` I can see a `DJCELERY` section with tables `Crontabs`, `Intervals`, `Periodic tasks`, `Tasks`, and `Workers`. There isn't any data on my Tasks though.

Can anyone point out what could be wrong or missing? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tutuDajuju led me in the right direction - there's more to it so I'll write it all up. I abandoned using `djcelery` in favor of `sqlalchemy` with a separate back-end database outside of `Django`.

Inside my `venv` I ran `pip install sqlalchemy`. I then put `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///celery_results.sqlite3'` in `settings.py`. This connected `Celery` to the new `SQLite` database to use for state/results.

Running `celery -A <projectapp>.celery:app worker` then showed the database in the startup message:

```
...
- ** ---------- .> transport: amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results: sqlite:///celery_results.sqlite3
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
...
```

At first I was worried because the database file wasn't created in my Django project dir. This is because I hadn't ran a task yet. Once I ran my first task, the database & tables were created correctly.

I verified task results were stored in the database by running a script:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///celery_results.sqlite3")
connection = engine.connect()

result = connection.execute("select * from celery_taskmeta")

for row in result:
    print(row)

connection.close()
```

I found the table names by:

```
print(engine.table_name())
```

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 2):

The [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-database-result-backend) mention a few different syntaxes, not sure what you tried is valid. Try the following:

```
# use a connection string
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///foo.db'
```

*Update*:

As in your comment, [the docs also mention](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend) it is also possible to use the Django ORM/Cache as a result backend. To do this, you must pass the setting you tried into your celery app config:

```
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
)
```

Alternatively, the docs also explain

> If you have connected Celery to your Django settings then you can add
>   this directly into your settings module (without the app.conf.update
>   part)

This is a reference to the configuration of the Celery app detailed in the same page. This basically means that if you configured your celery app in a module, **and** you add the Django settings module as a configuration source for Celery, **then** setting `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` in your Django settings module, as you did, will also work.

**file**:   *proj/proj/celery.py*

```
# important to pass the Django settings to your celery app
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

**file**:   *proj/proj/settings.py*

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

Comment: Hi, the Django docs [Using Celery with Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) specify that you can use `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',`. What you posted doesn't use `djcelery`, but instead uses `sqlalchemy`.